# ask the user for input (a sentence) and print out the longest word of that sentence

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I have this program ask the user for input (a sentence) and print out the longest word of that sentence.

```
package projectOne;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LongestWord {

//Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
//System.out.println("In 1 sentence tell me what is on your mind today.");
//String actualstring = keyboard.nextLine();

static String actualstring = keyboard.nextLine();
static String[] splitstring = actualstring.split(" ");

public static void main(String [] args){


    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("In 1 sentence tell me what is on your mind today.");
    //String actualstring = keyboard.nextLine();
    //String[] splitstring = actualstring.split(" ");

    LongWord();

}

public static void LongWord() {     
    String longword = "";
    for (int i=0; i<=splitstring.length-1; i++){    
    if (longword.length()<splitstring[i].length())
        longword = splitstring[i];  

    }


    System.out.println(longword);
    int replyLength = longword.length();
    System.out.println(replyLength);

    if (replyLength == 3)
        System.out.println("Hmmm tell me more about "+longword+" please");
    else if (replyLength == 4)
        System.out.println("Why do you feel "+longword+" is important?");
    else if (replyLength == 5)
         System.out.println("How does "+longword+" affect you?");
    else if (replyLength > 5)
         System.out.println("We seem to be making great progress with "+longword);
    else
        System.out.println("Is there something else you would like to discuss?");

   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you quite understand how methods work. In your main you should prompt the user for the line they'd like to enter and then you should read the entire line intro a `String` using the Scanner.nextLine() method and then you should pass said `String` into your longWord method for processing.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("In 1 sentence tell me what is on your mind today.");
   String sentence = keyboard.nextLine();

   longWord(sentence);
}

public static void longWord(String sentence) {
    //Process and print the longest word using the passed in String param
    //Splitting, looping, comparisons, output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    String maxword = null;
    str = str + ' ';
    int l = str.length();
    String word = "";
    int maxlength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        word = word + str.charAt(i);
        if (str.charAt(i + 1) == ' ') {
            if (word.length() > maxlength) {
                maxword = new String(word);
                maxlength = word.length();
            }
            word = "";
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Longest Word: " + maxword);

}
```

Comment: ahh, I thought that the split function found the character in the argument and split the string from that character into only two parts.  I didn't know that the second argument allowed you to specify. Fixed that